# InteropServices.COMException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I have a problem with an MVC proyect I have.

The stack is the following:

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80005000): Unknown error (0x80005000)     at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)     at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()     at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_Name()     at PosmanWeb2.Controllers.Helpers.SessionHelpers.GetGroup(SearchResult result)     at PosmanWeb2.Controllers.Helpers.SessionHelpers.GetPerfilAD(SearchResult result)     at PosmanWeb2.Controllers.Helpers.SessionHelpers.GetUser()     at PosmanWeb2.Controllers.Helpers.SessionHelpers.ConnectActiveDirectory()**

The Methods on SessionHelpers are part of the proyect, the last one seems to be having problems, the code is the following:

```
private static List<string> GetGroup(SearchResult result)
{
    List<string> nombresPerfilAD = new List<string>();

    foreach (var i in result.Properties["memberOf"])
    {
        var group = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://" + i);      
        nombresPerfilAD.Add(group.Name.Split('=')[1].ToUpper().Trim());             
    }

    return nombresPerfilAD;
}
```

What it basically does is save all the Active Directory profiles on a list.

One user in particular did not have this problem what another two have this exact problem.

I saw on other threads that it could be related to permission problems, but Im not 100% sure where to look.

Comment: try changing your code and use `PrincipalContext` you can get at the groups in AD without having to do it the old LDAP way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good solution in the current scope is not to bind to Active Directory. result.Properties["memberOf"] already contains group DN. You can get name from it without connecting to AD using IADsPathName interface (need to add a reference to ActiveDs com object). Also you can unescape special chars using this interface. E. g. if you group name is #Test it will be returned as escaped like \#Test. Thus you will solve your issue, increase performance and deal with characters escaping if you rewrite your method in the following way:

```
    private static List<string> GetGroup(SearchResult result)
    {
        List<string> nombresPerfilAD = new List<string>();
        IADsPathname pathname = new PathnameClass();
        pathname.SetDisplayType(2);
        pathname.EscapedMode = 4;

        foreach (string groupDn in result.Properties["memberOf"])
        {
            pathname.Set(groupDn, 4);
            nombresPerfilAD.Add(pathname.GetElement(0).ToUpper());
        }

        return nombresPerfilAD;
    }
```

It seems like binding instead of splitting by comma was made to avoid situations, when a group contains comma in its name. But what if group name contains "=" character? Old code will not work

P.S. If you use .NET 4 you need to set Embed Interop Types to false in ActiveDs properties (in project references)

P.P.S. Be aware, that memberOf attribute does not contain nested groups (userA -> groupA, groupA -> groupB => userA -> groupB) and user's primary group

Comment: Im trying to find the ActiveDs com Object, which one is it? I have the following:
Active DS IIS Extension Dll
Active DS IIS Extension Namespace Provider 
Active DS Type Library

Comment: Ok I found it, it was the Active DS Type Library, but when I try to instantiate the IADsPathname it gives me the following error: 
The type of interoperability "ActiveDs.PathnameClass" cant be embed, Use the aplicable Interface instead.

Comment: Ok, I changed the property, Sorry my mistake